# Unknown Coordinate System Cadastral?

Tags: coordinate-system

I have point data from a proprietary source that came in a coordinate system I do not recognize.  Here is an example:

Lat: 35205357  Long: -11.15933

It looks like a  combination of UTMs and incomplete dds.  This is supposed to be in or around Flagstaff, AZ.

What is this coordinate system?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please name the proprietary source (doing it in the question via **[edit]** would be good)?

Answer (score 2):

I just entered the coordinates into Google maps. If you change them to 35.205357, -111.59330 it puts you in the Flagstaff area. So The coordinates may have just had their decimal places in the wrong places or missing.

Answer (score 1):

The latitude value could be 35 20 53.57 while the longitude value could be -111 59 33. Or they could both be decimal degrees, with the appropriate insertion or change of position.